# responsive menu not fully working on phones

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, responsive

I found this responsive top menu with display flex and when I open it in the phone's hamburger menu is not there but when I'm decreasing the resolution of browser the hamburger menu is shown.

Please help me find some responsive top menu where is used display flex and fully working on all devices.

```css
header {
    background: #7EA6E0;
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    max-width: 1180px;
        height: 80px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
        -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 {
        color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
}

ul {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav__icon,
.nav__icon span {
    display: none;
}

.nav__icon {
    width: 36px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__icon span {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav__icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: 0;
}

.nav__icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 12px;
}

.nav__icon span:nth-of-type(3) {
    bottom: 0;
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(12px) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(12px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: none;
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-12px) rotate(45deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    header {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    h1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
        ul {
                -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 980;
    }
    ul li {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul li a {
                display: block;
        background: transparent;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
        color: #000;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .nav__icon,
    .nav__icon span {
        display: inline-block;
        transition: all .4s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 999;
    }
}
```

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {` is defining css rules that only apply if the width is 700px or less.  If that is not what you want, you can always increase that max-width

Comment: Can you provide a link to the menu?

Comment: I agree with Andy, it can't really be diagnosed without a link, or at least the HTML markup. Since the .nav__icon is display: inline-block, other items can be affecting it. Incidentally, have you tried the "Toggle device toolbar" in your browser's developer tools? Does it still happen there?

Comment: Please post the HTML for the menu. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

sorry i forget to add html sry

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>FlexBox Responsive Menu-css</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

 <header id="header" role="heading">
  <nav>
   <h1 class="logo">Panda Custom</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="nav__icon">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <!--/Nav-->
 </header>
 <!--/Header-->
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js'></script>



 <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```